# Entity framework linq include

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have the following Linq query I'm working with entity framework.

```
var res = from a in _db.Articles
                  from auth in a.Authors
                  where papers.Contains(a.JoomlaId)
                  select auth.Institution;
```

The problem is that my institution class has a variable named "`Type`" of type "`InstitutionType`" that I need to include, and I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: Don't call your variable "type", your future self will kill you

Comment: You do have a point, i don't deny it but if i call it InstitutionType, it will be like `Institution.InstitutionType` which doesn't seam ok either.

Comment: AssociatedType? I would try programmers exchange, institutiontype sounds good to me though, it doesnt sound like a static type

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var res = from a in _db.Articles.Include("Authors") 
                                .Include("Authors.Institution")
                                .Include("Authors.Institution.Type")
                  from auth in a.Authors
                  where papers.Contains(a.JoomlaId)
                  select auth.Institution;
```

Comment: Should have been `var res = from a in _db.Articles
       .Include("Authors")
       .Include("Authors.Institution")
       .Include("Authors.Institution.Type")
       from auth in a.Authors
       where papers.Contains(a.JoomlaId)
       select auth.Institution;` Can u please edit so i can mark it as an answer